# NGINX access module and internal DNS: How to allow only local clients

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, internal-dns

I searched through serverfault but couldn't find an answer to this. Maybe I just don't know the right keyword or it's a conceptual misunderstanding. Any help would be appreciated!

The situation:

1. My local services are running behind an NGINX reverse proxy
2. I use a [LAN DNS on the router (Draytek)](https://www.draytek.com/support/knowledge-base/5151) to resolve local requests to *.example.com directly to my local server (192.168.1.2).

Even if there is no internet connection, the domains will be resolved to the local server and all services are accessible. That's why I use the LAN DNS. So far, so good.

Now I want to only allow local clients to access certain services by using the [NGINX access module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) with:

```
allow 192.168.1.0/24;
deny all;
```

But NGINX only sees the public IP of the router instead of the IP of the client (192.168.1.100) and so every request is refused:

```
[...] access forbidden by rule, client: 123.123.123.123, server: service.example.de, request: [...]"
```

My question is:

**How can I distinguish between local and remote clients on NGINX in this scenario?**

[Link to network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjbgF.jpg)

---

Comment: Don't use NAT. DNS does *not* rewrite any IP's.

Answer (score 0):

First an assumption/condition, which is to check if your router adds the **X-Forwarded-For** header or something similar (keeps trace of the actual client IP)

You should resolve the client IP first, through [ngx_http_realip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)

The example configuration provided there:

```
set_real_ip_from  192.168.1.0/24;
set_real_ip_from  192.168.2.1;
set_real_ip_from  2001:0db8::/32;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

With this, the IP used for access checks should be the correct one (actual client).

One caveat is that with such configuration, attempts to add the router to the X-Forwarded-For header cannot be done *automatically* with proxy_add_x_forwarded_for, as the IP added through will have been altered by the previous directive.
That specific case has been discussed [on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279084/nginx-proxy-add-x-forwarded-for-and-real-ip-header)